# Microsoft Graph: Get-MgUser shows only 100 entries. How can I get all Users?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am reading all Users of my Azure-AD with the cmdlet

```
Get-MgUser
```

The output shows exactly 100 Objects. I expect over 200 entries. How can I get the missing Objects?

I use this command to get the ID of every User.

Comment: `Get-MgUser -All` ?? There's also a parameter `-PageSize` you can set to a higher value (int32)

Comment: Thank you very much. I somehow missed that. Do you want to write an answer? Then I can accept it.

Comment: Sure, just posted it. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.users/get-mguser?view=graph-powershell-beta) show, you can use either switch `-All` to the Get-MgUser cmdlet, which will list all pages, or use the `-PageSize` parameter where you can set the page size of results.

Apparently, the default pagesize is set to 100, so with PageSize you could do

```
Get-MgUser -PageSize 300  # or [int32]::MaxValue
```

Easier of course is to use the -All switch:

```
Get-MgUser -All
```

to receive all objects